# Area between the curves $y=x \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ and $y=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the problem:

Find the area between the curves: $y = x \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ and $y=0$, with $a>0$.

My thought is attempting to solve the inequality:

$x=-a, x=a$ or $x=0$ for $y=0$ to remain true.

So the area between the two must be:

$$\intop_0^a x \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \mathrm d x $$

Can someone verify my correctness?

Comment: Or maybe double to deal with the third quadrant part.

Comment: Good point. Prior, I had assumed I was only working in Q1, because a>0 but I realize that's not the case after thinking about it for a second. Thanks, that helped.